# Pass command via variable in shell

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have following code in my build script:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    make -j10 $1 2>&1 | tee log.txt && notify-send -u critical -t 7 "BUILD DONE"
else
    make -j10 $1 2>&1 | tee log.txt | grep -i --color "Error" && notify-send -u critical -t 7 "BUILD DONE"
fi
```

I tried to optimize it to:

```
local GREP=""
[[ ! -z "$1" ]] && GREP="| grep -i --color Error" && echo "Grepping for ERRORS"
make -j10 $1 2>&1 | tee log.txt "$GREP" && notify-send -u critical -t 7 "BUILD DONE"
```

But error thrown in make line if $1 isn't empty. I just can't figure out how to pass command with grep pipe through the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have already pointed out, you cannot, in general, expect a command in a variable to work.  [This is a FAQ.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

What you can do is execute commands conditionally.  Like this, for example:

```
( make -j10 $1 2>&1 && notify-send -u critical -t 7 "BUILD DONE" ) |
tee log.txt |
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    grep -i --color "Error"
else
    cat
fi
```

This has the additional unexpected benefit that the `notify-send` is actually conditioned on the exit code of `make` (which is probably what you intended) rather than `tee` (which I would expect to succeed unless you run out of disk or something).

(Or if you want the notification regardless of the success status, change `&&` to just `;` -- I think this probably makes more sense.)

This is one of those rare Useful Uses of `cat` (although I still feel the urge to try to get rid of it!)

Comment: I also imagine that the unquoted `$1` really should be double quoted `"$1"` but it is of course possible that you actually know what you are doing and have a good reason to want the shell to do whitespace splitting and wildcard expansion of the value in `$1`.  If not (and/or especially if you don't understand what I'm saying), it should definitely be `"$1"` instead.  Or perhaps you are looking for `${1:+"$1"}` which ends up quoted if non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put pipes in [command variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050):

```
$ foo='| cat'
$ echo bar $foo
bar | cat
```

The linked article explains how to do such things very well.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [@l0b0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23736420/2088135), the `|` will not be interpreted as you are hoping.

If you wanted to cut down on repetition, you could do something like this:

```
if [ $(make -j10 "$1" 2>&1 > log.txt) ]; then
    [ "$1" ] && grep -i --color "error" log.txt
    notify-send -u critical -t 7 "BUILD DONE"
fi
```

The inside of the test is common to both branches. Instead of using `tee` so that the output can be piped, you can just indirect the output to `log.txt`. If `"$1"` isn't empty, `grep` for any errors in `log.txt`. Either way, do the `notify-send`.